# Navigating to actual compilation errors in IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

IDEA has a handy shortcut for going to next/previous highlighting error in code, but it's useless when the highlighted errors are wrong (as they often are in Scala plugin). After compilation I get actual errors in the "Messages" panel, but clicking and scrolling there isn't too convenient. Is there a shortcut for going to next/previous *compilation* errors?

Comment: Do you mean the F2 / shift + F2 shortcuts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the Messages view is displayed, Ctrl-Alt-Up/Down shortcuts in the editor navigate you to the previous/next error from the Messages view. (Those keyboard shortcuts work for other views such as the Find Usages results as well).